# Error no such file or directory in VScode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to include header files from the atmel avr folder to work with arduino. Despite trying to include the directory of the files, it still prompts me with "No such file or directory" when compyling. The files are located inside "C:\repositories\arduino_testing\include\avr"
What am I doing wrong?

`main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "avr\io.h"

int main(){

    printf("This is a C code");

    return 0;
}
```

`tasks.json`

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-I C:\\repositories\\arduino_testing\\include",
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cpp.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\cpp.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

`c_cpp_properties`

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                //"${workspaceFolder}/**",
                //"C:\\repositories\\arduino_testing\\avr",
                "C:\\repositories\\arduino_testing\\include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your c_cpp_properties.json file, you need to add the path to the avr folder in the includePath array.

```
"includePath": [
    //"${workspaceFolder}/**",
    "C:\\repositories\\arduino_testing\\include\\avr"
],
```

Comment: Already had that previously, it compiled with io.h, but other header file it would not compile, also showed this error since sfr_defs.h is being called inside io.h: ""message": "cannot open source file \"avr/sfr_defs.h\" (dependency of \"io.h\")"

Comment: It looks like you don't have the avr library installed. If you are using PlatformIO, you can install it by adding it as a framework in platformio.ini.
You can find more information on how to install the avr library here: https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/platforms/atmelavr.html#framework

Comment: No, I don't have it installed, I'll take a look on that link, thanks @DotNetRussell

Answer (score 0):

> `#include "avr\io.h"`

`#include` **always** uses forward slashes `/` as path separator, no matter what host system you are using.

That system header is part of the GNU tools for AVR and provided by [AVR-LibC](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__io.html), hence:

`#include <avr/io.h>`

Also notice that this is a sytem header, thus enclose in `<` and `>`, not in `"`'s.

There is no need for `-isystem <path>` (or `-I <path>` for that matter) as far as the GNU tools are concerned.  You might need to provide the headers to IDEs that need their contents to display locations of macro definitions, though.

If you can only compile with `-isystem <path>` (or `-I <path>` for that matter) your toolchain installation is broken, and you should get a working toolchain. Same if it doesn't work with `-isystem` (or `-I`): toolchain is broken.

So show the include paths, add `-v` to the compiler options and inspect its output:

```
> avr-gcc -v ...
[snip many lines]
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 $install/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/8.5.0/include
 $install/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/8.5.0/include-fixed
 $install/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/8.5.0/../../../../avr/include
End of search list.
...
```

where the last line belongs to the AVR-LibC system includes. Resolving all these `..`'s, the path is `$install/avr/include`, and it should contain a folder `avr` which contains `io.h` etc.

Comment: That is not the problem, already tried forward slash, back slash and <> but still the error "avr/io.h: No such file or directory" shows up

Comment: Using `\ ` *is* as problem. Even if you have a working toolchain, using backslashes in C/C++ includes won't work.  If some files or part of installation is missing, then that problem comes atop of it, of course. That said, you need a working toolchain **and** `/`'s.